# An algorithm for aggregation of similar sequences

Tags: algorithm

Let's say you have a list of similar sequences, such as

```
a a a a
a b a a a
x a a a a y
...
```

You want to detect a common aggregate of all these sequences, such as

```
x? a b? a a a y?
```

where operator `?` specifies that element is optional.

What algorithm would you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the [sequence alignment algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment) used in bioinformatics.

More specifically, since you have a list, [multiple sequence alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_sequence_alignment). The [Viterbi algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viterbi_algorithm) should do.

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you convert your list to suffix tree then it will be very simple recursive solution but I am not sure about asymptotic complexity

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out smith-Waterman algorithm that is used for performing sequence alignments.

Comment: That one only does pairwise alignment.